# OAuth - "No module named authlib"

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I'm running superset on MacOS in docker and I'm trying to get OAuth working.

I’ve edited the config file `/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py` and added the OAuth configuration.

One of the lines I added was

```
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
```

This required me to import the auth types as below:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import (
    AUTH_OID,
    AUTH_REMOTE_USER,
    AUTH_DB,
    AUTH_LDAP,
    AUTH_OAUTH,
)
```

When I try to start up superset with the following command:  `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 250, in __init__
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authlib'
```

I'm fairly new to docker itself. How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody else comes across this, the solution was to add the `Authlib` module to the python env on the docker image.

The process for adding a new python module to the docker image is documented here: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/README.md#local-packages

Quoted below in case that file changes:

```
If you want to add python packages in order to test things like DBs locally, you can simply add a local requirements.txt (./docker/requirements-local.txt) and rebuild your docker stack.

Steps: 
1. Create ./docker/requirements-local.txt 
2. Add your new packages 
3. Rebuild docker-compose 
  a. docker-compose down -v 
  b. docker-compose up
```

Important was running `docker-compose up` and **not** `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`. The latter does not seem to rebuild the docker image.

Comment: There is no need to rebuild the image. In my case I just added authlib dependency in `./docker/requirements-local.txt` and they were automatically picked up in `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`.

Comment: You have to add in `requirements-local.txt` -> `Authlib==0.15.5` as  Ruchit Patel wrote above